# Pass pyfiles and arguments to DataProcPySparkOperator

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer

I am trying to pass **arguments and zipped pyfiles** to a temporary Dataproc Cluster in Composer

```
spark_args = {
    'conn_id': 'spark_default',
    'num_executors': 2,
    'executor_cores': 2,
    'executor_memory': '2G',
    'driver_memory': '2G',
}    

task = dataproc_operator.DataProcPySparkOperator(
                task_id='spark_preprocess_{}'.format(name),
                project_id=PROJECT_ID,
                cluster_name=CLUSTER_NAME,
                region='europe-west4',
                main='gs://my-bucket/dist/main.py',
                pyfiles='gs://my-bucket/dist/jobs.zip',
                dataproc_pyspark_properties=spark_args,
                arguments=['--name', 'test', '--date', self.date_exec],
                dag=subdag
            )
```

But I get the following error, any idea how to correctly format the arguments?

> Invalid value at 'job.pyspark_job.properties[1].value' (TYPE_STRING)

Comment: This is likely because you're using integers in `spark_args`. The properties are strictly strings so just add quotation marks.

Comment: The comment makes sense as conn_id is properties[0], and num_executors is properties[1] which has an integer value. @kwn, can you please confirm if this resolves the error?

Comment: It resolves the error indeed, thanks a lot @tix !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in [the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60194765/pass-pyfiles-and-arguments-to-dataprocpysparkoperator#comment106469651_60194765), the issues is that `spark_args` has non-string values, but it should contain only strings per error message:

```
Invalid value at 'job.pyspark_job.properties[1].value' (TYPE_STRING)
```